# Are lambda functions CLOS objects?

Tags: function, common-lisp, sbcl, clos

When I do this:

```lisp
(defparameter thing #'(lambda () (+ 1 1)))
```

The returned value for `thing` is

`#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {53A11BEB}>`

This print out looks a lot like the print-object for a CLOS.

So, I thought id like to see the actual function detail in the `print-object`.

I cannot seem to find out the name of the function object to use in my `list-class-slots` function:

```lisp
(defun list-class-slots (class)
  (mapcar #'sb-mop::slot-definition-name
     (sb-mop::class-direct-slots (class-of (make-instance class)))))
```

I tried `sb-mop::funcallable-standard-class` but this returns nil. I also tried `function` and the error told me to use the funcallable-standard-class.

Am I wrong here? is the original lambda printout NOT related to CLOS at all? if not, what is the source of the function printout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function created with `lambda` is an object, yes. It's an instance of the [system class `function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fn.htm):

```
* (class-of thing)
#<SB-PCL:SYSTEM-CLASS COMMON-LISP:FUNCTION>
```

Functions are printed in an [implementation-dependent manner](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_acm.htm), in practice often in the convention for an *unreadable* value (`#<...>`). It appears that SBCL has a specialization of the [`print-object` generic method](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) for functions.

```
* (find-method #'print-object '() (mapcar #'find-class '(function t)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD COMMON-LISP:PRINT-OBJECT #'T {100042B4C3}>
```

Indeed, [here it is](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/ed21037b10b87d40c29d16aaf0c47fac4203a829/tree/src/code/print.lisp#l2053). You can poke around in it to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

In such a printed representation `#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {53A11BEB}>`, the first thing usually (by convention) is the type of the thing. Thus it is of type `FUNCTION`. See the standard.

CLOS also has a feature to define function objects which are both CLOS objects and callable functions. The use of those is rarely seen.

> cannot seem to find out the name of the function object

The function object does not have a name.